# How to keep Ultrawide (32:9) ratio in Elden Ring

Tags: elden-ring

When using the Flawless widescreen app and starting Elden Ring, it starts off well in 32:9 ratio. But then in about a minute, it reverts back to the original default ratio and the two black bars reappear. Any advice on how to keep 32:9 ratio in Elden Ring?